# selecting granparent/parent/child relationships in DOM with Selenium/jQuery

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an HTML tree structure similar to the following

```
- Root folder
---Child folder 1
------Grand child folder a
---Child folder 2
------Grand child folder a
------Grand child folder b
---Child folder 3
etc...
```

The HTML is comprised of nested tables and some names are identical between different folders.  I need to be able to search the DOM for Root/child folder x/grand child y.

I'm using Selenium WebDriver in Java.

**What we've tried already:**

```
$(\".wdk_ContentRepositoryBrowse tr a.sbLinkGeneral:contains('" + parentFolderName + "')\").parent('td').prev('td').children('a.sbLinkGeneral').children('img').attr('alt') || \".wdk_ContentRepositoryBrowse tr a.sbLinkGeneral:contains('" + childFolderName + "')\").parent('td').prev('td').children('a.sbLinkGeneral').children('img').attr('alt');";
```

This method works as long as it is the first folder below the parent, is problematic because we might have to traverse a very large number of rows to the get to the correct child folder.

**What we're currently using:**

```
String courseLink = "return $(\"a\").filter(function() {  return $(this).text() == '"+ folderName` + "';}).length";
```

The limitation with this is that it doesn't verify that the parent/grand parent folders match.  My questions are:

1. Can I nest filter functions and if so how?
2. Is this the best way to do this or is there another method that I'm not thinking about?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain on what will be your sample input and sample output?

Comment: Purus, I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you are asking for.